# Wkhtmltopdf fixed header/footer options print extra blank pages. How to debug and fix?

Tags: 8

So for this I am using entity print 2.2.0 with WKHTML 0.12.6 wit these patches:

```
            "drupal/entity_print": {
            "Add Export to Word Support": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-11-22/2733781-47.patch",
            "Adding page numbers in footer in pdf": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-05-29/entity_print-custom_footer-2823430-7.patch"
        }
```

The second one allows for a creation of a hook to add extra options and I have this:

```
function mymodule_print_pdf_wkhtmltopdf_options_alter(&$options) { 
  $print_dir = '/Users/user/Sites/localhost/d8/web/print';
  $header = $print_dir.'/header.html';
  $footer = $print_dir.'/footer.html';
  $options['header-html'] = $header;
  $options['footer-html'] = $footer;
  $options['enable-local-file-access'] = [$header, $footer];
}
```

This applies a header and footer to every page but adds two extra empty pages and the first one has two headers. The module debug route skips these options so how do I go about debugging this?

And I did try this with dompdf. It is easier, but unfortunately it doesn't support rtl.

Note: A downgrade to wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 and doing away with the 'enable-local-file-access' is one fix.

Comment: Where has `$print_dir` been defined/set?

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have omitted it.  the files are located in a folder named print right under /web directory.

Comment: I added a definition for it.